# S3 List all subfolders of a bucket produces AccessDenied , even though the bucket is Public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Consider the following policy in S3 :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AxelPolly12424242",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt242554354",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucketname/*",
            "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","examples"]}}
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to hit my bucket name  `https://mycoolbucketname.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/examples`:

we get:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>KJLFSDHJJKGDFJKLGJDFKLGJLDF</RequestId>
    <HostId>GLKSFDNGJKLFDJGKLDFJGKLFDJGFDGEOT89GJROIGIKDSFSDJSD</HostId>
</Error>
```

What's wrong with this policy and how can we list all subfolders of a bucket , when we've also unchecked
`Block public access (bucket settings)` under Permissions tab.

Comment: Please clarify what you are wanting to allow people to do. What do you mean by "hit my bucket"? Are you wanting to allow people to download any content in the `examples` directory (if they know the URL), or are you wanting to allow them to **list** the contents? These are two very different requirements. Also, are you wanting to allow people to do this via a web browser URL, or via the AWS CLI (or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

[s3:prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) applies to **bucket resources**, not objects. So instead of:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucketname/*",
```

you should have:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucketname",
```

Comment: But now when I try to access my files the folder : `https://mycoolbucketname.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/examples/` I get : `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>` , and when typing (without the Slash at the end) `https://mycoolbucketname.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/examples` , I get : `<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>`

Comment: @JAN Can you update your question with examples of object keys that want to list?

Comment: Sure , I want to list the files in the browser and download whatever I want to pick , but now it doesn't even show me the files

Comment: @JAN Sorry. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve in "a browser". The policy is correct and it works when you use aws cli: `aws s3 ls s3://mycoolbucketname/examples  --no-sign-request` or `aws s3 ls s3://mycoolbucketname  --no-sign-request`.

Comment: I want to achieve this : list all files in the subfolder `examples` when any public user tries to access the url `https://mycoolbucketname.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/examples/` , and as you can see , I get AccessDenied.

Comment: @JAN You can't do this just by pasting the url in a browser. You have to call proper AWS API procedures to `ListBucket`. Your users have to use AWS CLI which I provided or AWS SDK. If you want them to use only browser, you have to develop some custom website for this. Maybe some website already exist for that.